# how to map documents to controls

Tags: tensorflow, model, nlp

I have about 500 documents (1 page) that have been mapped to about 3000 short paragraphs (1-2 sentences). These paragraphs describe how the document needs to be reviewed. Each document can and is typically mapped to several paragraphs.

For example, if the document is about the procedures to follow for a certain production process, the paragraphs are about who needs to review the document, what needs to be reviewed, what is the goal of the review, how frequently it should be done etc.

I want to develop a model that can suggest the possible paragraphs from a given document. I have chosen to follow the below approach:

Prepare the data (tokenize, remove stop words, lemmatize etc.)
Consider all the paragraphs as one single output, i.e. concatenate them
Use a sequence to sequence model (tensorflow encoder/decoder RNN model) to map the document to the concatenated paragraphs
Use the outputted sequence to find the closest paragraphs as a suggestion
Given the small sample size, the model in step 3 does not converge.

I am trying to improve the modeling approach (e.g. one can map each sentence in the document to each paragraph to increase the sample size) or to find alternative approaches. What are some typical models for such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the easiest way to handle this would be to create a binary classifier for each paragraph that says whether it applies to the input document or not.

If you want to look for more detail on problems like this, what you're dealing with is called a **multi-label classification** problem. A common example would be guessing tags for a Stack Overflow problem based on the text. Unless there's some close textual relationship between your paragraphs and documents (like overlapping word use), it's probably best to think of your paragraphs as **labels** rather than using their contents in your model.

Also, given the amount of data you have, I would start with something more basic than neural networks, like Naive Bayes or SVM, to verify that the approach will work. Since you're working in Python already, Gensim has a [variety of multi-label classifiers](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).

Comment: Your suggestion is useful. I believe one can approach the problem from a "Recommendation System" perspective. I am wondering how I can measure the similarities among the large documents themselves and also the small paragraphs though. In principle, I can use a text similarity measure instead of relying on the existing mappings.  But I am not completely sure.